# Is it okay to store a lot of data with Async Storage? [React Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase, asyncstorage

I’m working on a react native app where I have my firebase database storing an inventory of about 10000 items.
So I need to store that data locally and I was thinking of saving each item into his own key with async storage.
Is that okay or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Note that on Android AsyncStorage has an upper size limit of 6MB.

Comment: The previous comment is true, but this limit can be changed by adding an `AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB` property to `android/gradle.properties` and set the value to the new max MB.

Answer (score 5):

> AsyncStorage has slow runtime and has no indexing capabilities.
>   Because AsyncStorage only accepts string as its value, all data must
>   first be serialized into string before being inserted, and
>   deserialized once retrieved. This is why you should not use
>   AsyncStorage when dealing with a large amount of data

you can read this article for more information on how AsyncStorage works while dealing with large data: https://codeburst.io/tackling-react-native-storage-part-1-d27b2bfa480f

Answer (score 2):

You can use AsyncStorage, it will always take a time when you try to retrieve the data from it.

There are other possible way like:

1) React Native SQLite 2

2) [React Native Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-storage)

3) [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)

4) [React Native Local MongoDB](https://github.com/antoniopresto/react-native-local-mongodb)